# Which Data Type in C# Should I use to enter data into a Decimal Column in T-SQL?

Tags: c#, t-sql, types, sqldatatypes

I am having a hard time trying to figure out which data type I would use in C# to enter data into my table in my database which contains a decimal(5,2). When I tried using a C# decimal data type, it said that It had an error converting numeric to decimal. When I tried string, It said that it could not convert nvarchar to decimal. When I tried float... Same thing happened, except the excuse was a "real" data type. double also failed to work.

I have a stored procedure which enters the data into my table, but before I run of and cast data types in my stored procedure to the actual decimal, is there any other way I can rather Convert a c# data type to fit in my decimal(5,2) field?

```
private void btnAddClientComputer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLCommands comm = new SQLCommands();
    try
    {
        comm.AddClientComputer(int.Parse(cbCustomerID.Text), cbAction.Text, decimal.Parse(tbCost.Text));
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The cost you have entered is invalid. Please ensure the cost is above 0, and is an actual number", "Invalid Input at Cost", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
}
```

...

```
public void AddClientComputer(int CustomerID, string Action, decimal Cost)
{
    try
    {
        comm = new SqlCommand("UspAddClientComputer", conn); // Stored Procedure - see sql file
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", Action);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cost", Cost);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

...

```
CREATE TABLE ClientComputers
            (ClientComputerID int Identity(1,1) primary key clustered
            ,CustomerID int
            ,Action varchar(7) check (Action = 'Upgrade' OR Action = 'Store')
            ,Cost decimal(5,2) check (Cost > 0)
            ,Constraint FKCustomerComputer FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID));
Go
```

...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddClientComputer @CustomerID int, @Action varchar(7), @Cost decimal(5,2)
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TrnAddClientComputer;
     INSERT INTO [TCTdb].[dbo].[ClientComputers]
           ([CustomerID]
           ,[Action]
           ,[Cost])
     VALUES
           (@CustomerID
           ,@Action
           ,@Cost)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION TrnAddClientComputer;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TrnAddClientComputer;

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,
               @ErrorSeverity,
               @ErrorState
               );
END CATCH
GO
```

[image]

Comment: .NET's `decimal` would be logical and most appropriate choice... can you show us some code that caused this error you had??

Comment: sure. Give me a moment to edit my post

Comment: Are you using decimal(5,2)  for stored procedure parameter as well?

Comment: well, after editing my post, I see yes :D

Comment: Just wondering: you have `DECIMAL(5,2)` - what range of values do you expect this type to be able to hold?? Any chance you might expect 5 digits before and 2 digits after the decimal point? That would be **incorrect** - dec(5,2) means: 5 digits **total**, 2 of which after the decimal point - so you're limiting yourself to values to a max of `999.99`. Could that be the core of the problem in the end??

Comment: Valuable information. thank you, seems like I was in the wrong party here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to fix my problem under the circumstances, thanks to sll bringing a few things under my attention. The following code worked for me.

```
private void btnAddClientComputer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLCommands comm = new SQLCommands();
    double trycost;
    if (double.TryParse(tbCost.Text,out trycost))
    {
        comm.AddClientComputer(int.Parse(cbCustomerID.Text), cbAction.Text, trycost);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The cost you have entered is invalid. Please ensure the cost is above 0, and is an actual number", "Invalid Input at Cost", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
}
```

...

```
public void AddClientComputer(int CustomerID, string Action, double Cost)
    {
        try
        {
            comm = new SqlCommand("UspAddClientComputer", conn); // Stored Procedure - see sql file
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", Action);
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cost",Cost));
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

..Here comes the solution part. I replaced the Decimal(5,2) with smallmoney.

```
CREATE TABLE ClientComputers
            (ClientComputerID int Identity(1,1) primary key clustered
            ,CustomerID int
            ,Action varchar(7) check (Action = 'Upgrade' OR Action = 'Store')
            ,Cost smallmoney check (Cost > 0)
            ,Constraint FKCustomerComputer FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID));
Go

---------STORED PROCEDURES
--ADD CLIENT COMPUTER
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddClientComputer @CustomerID int, @Action varchar(7), @Cost smallmoney
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TrnAddClientComputer;
     INSERT INTO [TCTdb].[dbo].[ClientComputers]
           ([CustomerID]
           ,[Action]
           ,[Cost])
     VALUES
           (@CustomerID
           ,@Action
           ,@Cost)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION TrnAddClientComputer;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TrnAddClientComputer;

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,
               @ErrorSeverity,
               @ErrorState
               );
END CATCH
GO
```

Thanks to everyone who has tried. This answered my question. Right Idea, **WRONG** data type.

Comment: Nice to hear that you've sorted it out but still not clear why decimal(,) is not work for you, take a look at this article http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/Sql/Arithmetic-overflow-error.aspx

Comment: Is it possible that It is a bug perhaps? your code seems to be the right way to go about it (its like 11pm here now , and I am tired and do not concentrate as well). This may be something far more deeper. what if the decimal(5,2) was too small? I tested it with the value of 4599.95 (Supposed to work with South-African rand)

Comment: Yep, you can define decimal(8,3) for instance and give it a try

Comment: That may have been just it. I was scrooging on storage space. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try out

```cs
 comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cost", Cost));
```

BTW,

you can refactor following block

```
 try
    {
        comm.AddClientComputer(int.Parse(cbCustomerID.Text), cbAction.Text, decimal.Parse(tbCost.Text));
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The cost you have entered is invalid. Please ensure the cost is above 0, and is an actual number", "Invalid Input at Cost", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
```

to

```
// TODO: do the same for int.Parse as well
decimal userDefinedCost;
if (decimal.TryParse(tbCost.Text, out userDefinedCost))
{
     comm.AddClientComputer(int.Parse(cbCustomerID.Text), cbAction.Text, userDefinedCOst);
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("The cost you have entered is invalid. Please ensure the cost is above 0, and is an actual number", "Invalid Input at Cost", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
```

Comment: no luck. this code above still gives me the same error. Did give me an Idea however. I am facepalming for using decimal in the first place, Could have used smallmoney. but now this may be interesting to find out how to solve still...

Comment: @Eon Rusted du Plessis: what if you use the most specific code: `SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@cost", SqlDbType.Decimal, 5); param.Precision = 2;` - does that make any difference?

Comment: I can see if it works, but as stated in my answer, I swung my decimal datatype to smallmoney, as I was working with a Cost of an service. Decimal was good to use (if I got it to work) but my intuition says that smallmoney just may be better (money datatype is larger , and nearly no-one is THAT rich)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you add the decimal parameter with the type specified. That means not just using AddWithValue, but creating a Parameter object.

I suspect that the problem is being caused because the code is not managing to convert cleanly.

ETA :

Your code was

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@Cost",SqlDbType.Decimal);
comm.Parameters["@Cost"].Value = Cost;
```

You need to to do something like ( As I said I don't have syntax checking easily available )

```
SqlParameter param= new SqlParameter("@Cost", SqlDbType.Decimal, Cost);//there are more parameters which I cannot remember
comm.Parameters.Add(param);
```

The important thing is to create the object where you can pass in all of the parameters which can define it clearly as a SQL decimal.

Comment: Ok, I used a parameter object (I think). I said comm.Parameters.Add("@Cost",SqlDbType.Decimal); then followed up with comm.Parameters["@Cost"].Value = Cost;   Gave me the same error

Comment: Have you tried my version using new SqlParameter(...)? I've the same code using SP + decimal(,) and all workign fine

Comment: Just have. Same Error. Im gonna try something quick. It may have been the wrong datatype I had to use.

Comment: Ok , I have solved my problem, but it is way off line what happened to this question. I will post my answer now.